# The minimal divisible extension

Tags: topological-groups

For a prime number $p$, $F_{p}$ is the p-adic number groups and $J_{p}$ is the p-adic integer groups. Is $F_{p}$, the minimal divisible extension of $J_{p}$?

Comment: Divisible group extension, or divisible $J_p$-algebra extension?

Comment: I don't know what a minimal divisible extension is, but I do know that every $p$-adic number $q$ is the unique solution to $p^n q=z$ for some natural number $n$ and $p$-adic integer $z$. So no proper subgroup of the $p$-adic numbers containing the $p$-adic integers is divisible.